# Поиск оптимального кольца

Tags: c++, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Помогите пожалуйста с решением задания.
На вход из файла поступает N-ное количество значений x,y и значение r. Задание состоит в том, чтобы найти координаты точек, являющихся вершинами фигуры Кольцо внутри которой будет лежать наибольшее количество точек.В моем случае вершиной фигуры будет являться центр кольца.
Необходимо исключить повторяющиеся точки и вывести координаты вершины x;y при которой в фигуре будет лежать наибольшее количество точек.

1)На данный момент у меня есть:

1.значение r

2.заполненный массив с координатами x

3.заполненный массив с координатами y

также количество точек x и y было уравнено, так что точки x;y будут попарно составлять одну отчку в нашей системе координат

условие для проверки принадлежности точек к фигуре я представил так:

1)сначал смещаем координаты x y, вычитая из них координаты вершины

далее идет проверка условия:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

данный фрагмент кода работает некорректно, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с причиной или найти альтернативное решение:

```
float x0;
float y0;
float x1;
float y1;
int k;
int e=0;
float otvet_x;
float otvet_y;

for (int i{};i<a;i++)
{
 x0=*(x+i);
 y0=*(y+i);
    for (int j{};j<a;j++)
    {
      x1=*(x+j);
      y1=*(y+j);

      x1=fabs(x1)-fabs(x0);
      y1=fabs(y1)-fabs(y0);
        if ((x1 || y1)>0)
        {
         if ( ((x1*x1+y1*y1)>=r*r)&&((x1*x1+y1*y1)<=((2*r)*(2*r))) )
            k=0;
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (k>e) e=k;
    otvet_x=*(x+i);
    otvet_y=*(y+i);
}
cout<<"При вершине кольца с координатами: x="<<otvet_x<<" y="<<otvet_y;
cout<<" фигура будет содержать наибольше количество точек:"<<e;
cout<<" при радиусе= "<<r<<endl;
```

Comment: *данный фрагмент кода работает некорректно* – с этого момента поподробнее, пожалуйста. Что **должен делать** данный фрагмент и что он **делает сейчас**? В чём именно проблема?

Comment: @V-Mor мой фрагмент кода должен сначала брать первую точку и проверять оставшиеся точки в массивах на условие принадлежности к фигуре, переменная a в моем коде - количество элементов в массиве(количество точек) . Условие ((x1 || y1)>0)  было использовано мной дабы исключить повторы при проверке точек. В настоящий момент моя программа выводит неверный результат....

Comment: У вас центр кольца *обязан* находиться в одной из точек?

Comment: "вершиной фигуры будет являться центр кольца" - это бред?

Comment: @Harry в моем случае я должен представить каждую точку как центр кольца и проверить сколько в ней будет лежать точек из оставшегося массива при данном мне r  , вывести же я должен координаты той точки, в которой будет лежать наибольшее количество точек

Comment: @Igor Мы каждую точку представляем как (x0,y0) в декартовой системе координат и вокруг нее строим фигуру "кольцо". оставшиеся же точки мы должны проверить на принадлежность к этой фигуре. Думаю так задание будет звучать более корректно

Comment: Зачем в этих выражениях `fabs` - `x1=fabs(x1)-fabs(x0);`?

Comment: ... и что делает эта проверка `if ((x1 || y1)>0)`?

Comment: ... и почему обнуляется `k`?

Comment: @Igor if ((x1 || y1)>0) я использовал чтобы исключить повторы точек, а x1=fabs(x1)-fabs(x0) чтобы сместитить координаты ближе к точке, но сейчас я начинаю понимать что я сделал некорректно

Comment: @igor k я обнулял чтобы при проверке каждой точки был счетчик , но видимо не в тот цикл воткнул

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, тогда ваш переборный код должен иметь примерно такой вид (не компилировал, мог и очепятаться...):

```
int count = -1, idx = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
{
    int in = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < a; ++j)
    {
        double dist = (x[j]-x[i])*(x[j]-x[i])+(y[j]-y[i])*(y[j]-y[i]);
        if (dist > r*r && dist < 4*r*r) in++;
    }
    if (in > count)
    {
        idx = i;
        count = in;
    }
}

cout << idx << "  " << count;
```

Можно немного оптимизировать, типа, вычислять `r*r` заранее, но, думаю, оптимизатор тоже справится :) Возиться и выбрасывать центральную точку - не вижу смысла, ну, посчитает ее разок...

Comment: Добрый день, больше спасибо за ответ. Не совсем понимаю как работает ваш алгоритм

Comment: Просто полный перебор. Поочередно беру точку в качестве центральной, и смотрю, сколько точек попадает в кольцо (квадрат расстояния от r^2 до 4r^2. Запоминаю текущий максимум. Все.

Comment: Я не совсем понял if и что происходит в нем, нам ведь надо вывести координаты x и y

Comment: Если количество точек в кольце для данной центральной точки превышает ранее достигнутый максимум - запоминаем новый максимум и индекс точки. Координаты выводите под конец как `x[idx]` и `y[idx]`.

Comment: не понимаю, почему то все равно некорректно работает....

Comment: Ну дайте ваши данные, посмотрим...

Comment: видимо проблема была в том, что по моей логике при  x^2+y^2=r^2 и x^2+y^2=4r^2 точка будет принадлежать